# What does this pseudo-jquery function(r) script do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have this in the HEAD of our site, and we're not sure what it does. It might have been a debug thing left over from a consulting firm? Thanks for any clues.

```
<script>
    (function (r) {
        _ready = {
            q: function () {
                return r;
            }
        };
        $ = function (f) {
            if (typeof f === "function") {
                r.push(arguments);
            }
            return $;
        };
        jQuery = $.ready = $;
    }([]));
</script>
```

FYI, the reason we're looking at this critically is that it seems to conflict with some other jquery libraries, such as NRelate's.

Comment: Hmmm it looks like it's wiring up `document.ready`?

Comment: It might be a placeholder for jQuery. If for any reason jQuery not loads this way your pages will not generate errors. Does your jQuery loads from a CDN or somewhere outside your site?

Comment: I agree, it's a jQuery placeholder. +1

Comment: So it looks like it's supporting jquery code embedded in the middle of the HTML document. Which unfortunately means if we rip this out, some things may not work.

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend (if its possible) to findout those embedded codes in your body and place them after loading `jQuery.js`. I dont think, its a good practise...its just a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://blog.vervestudios.co/blog/2011/07/default.aspx/) will help **for sure**

From the link given above,

> It setups jQuery.ready Callbacks Before jQuery is Loaded

**e.g.**

Suppose you have jQuery in body like this,

```
 <div id="main">
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#main").prepend( "<p>Heyo!</p>" );
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div>...more HTML...</div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

It wont work, since jQuery is being loaded at bottom and you are trying to use it before that.

So, we do this workaround,

```
<head>
    <script>
        (function(a){
             _ready = {
                q: function () {
                  return r;
                }
               };

             $ = function (f) {
               if (typeof f === "function") {
                r.push(arguments);
               }
             return $;
            };

            jQuery=$.ready=$;
        }([]));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#main" ).prepend( "<p>Heyo!</p>" );
            });
        </script>
        <div>...more HTML...</div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function( i, s, q, l ) {
            for( q = window._ready.q(), l = q.length; i < l; ) {
                $.apply( this, s.call( q[ i++ ] ) );
            }
            window._ready.q = undefined;
        }( 0, Array.prototype.slice ));
    </script>
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

What the first script does is emulate jQuery's ready function by storing the argments of any calls to $.ready where the first argument is a function into an array. This array is private to our globally scoped `_ready.q` method, which, when called, returns the array.

The second script loops through the array by calling `_ready.q()` and then applys the arguments originally passed to our imposter $.ready to the real $.ready.

**P.S.** its a self invoking function in which an empty array is passed with variable name `r`.
Refer [this](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

Comment: the code you've linked to is similar, but not quite identical - you've confirmed the theory I was working on in my answer, though!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, added more code (I got your feeling abt after a year visit).

Comment: Yep, you've found it. But the bigger question: is this a sane thing to do? Is it really the best option?

Comment: @Jashwant in this version you need to call `_ready.q()`, not just evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

`r` will be the empty array passed into the function at the end.

Fully annotated copy:

```
//         v--- receives the [] passed in below
(function (r) {
    // Creates an implicit global variable called `_ready`
    // (or overwrites one that's already there)
    _ready = {
        // Makes `r` available via `_ready.q()` or
        // `window._ready.q()`
        q: function () {
            return r;
        }
    };
    // Creates an implicit global variable called `$`
    // (or overwrites one that's already there)
    $ = function (f) {
        if (typeof f === "function") {
            r.push(arguments);
        }
        return $;
    };

    // Creates/overwrites the global variable `jQuery` and `$.ready`
    // with the function defined above
    jQuery = $.ready = $;
}([]));
//^^-- the value passed to r
```

It would *seem* to allow you to create an array of functions to call when jQuery is actually loaded, based on your taking over the `jQuery`, `$`, and `$.ready` symbols. The code to actually **do** that is not shown. The array will be accessible to whatever code actually uses it via `_ready.q()` (or `window._ready.q()`).

And to call it convoluted and in need of *serious* commenting (not to mention declaring the implicit global — *shudder* —) would be an understatement.

See also:

- [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm intrigued :)

Comment: to be fair, there's no way for this code to work _without_ creating at least two global variables.

Comment: @Alnitak: (I count three.) Perhaps, but they don't have to be *implicit*.

Comment: ah yes, I missed the aliasing of `jQuery` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's creating a list of all of the jQuery functions called (and the supplied parameters), probably before jQuery is actually loaded.

I expect you'll find some other piece of code that reads the contents of `_ready.q()` and passes them to jQuery once it's actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`r` is the empty array which is located at the bottom `[]`, basically `r` is an alias of the array which will be used inside the anonymous function as such `r.push` will push an item into the empty array

`(function(){ ... })()` is defined as an anonymous function.